# Reading XML node attribute values from nodes with the same name

Tags: c#, xml

My XML looks like this:

```
<Settings>
  <Display_Settings>
    <Screen>
      <Name Name="Screen" />
      <ScreenTag Tag="Screen Tag" />
      <LocalPosition X="12" Y="81" Z="28" />
      <Width Width="54" />
      <Height Height="912" />
    </Screen>
     <Screen>
      <Name Name="Screen" />
      <ScreenTag Tag="Screen Tag" />
      <LocalPosition X="32" Y="21" Z="28" />
      <Width Width="54" />
      <Height Height="912" />
    </Screen>
  </Display_Settings>
</Settings>
```

How am I able to read in the two different Local Position X attribute values from two different nodes that have the same name?

*Edit*

Sorry, forgot to add the code I have at the moment that reads in a singular local position attribute value from one screen node:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("C:\\Test.xml");
var screenPosition = xdoc.Descendants("Screen").First().Element("LocalPosition");
int screenX1 = int.Parse(screenPosition1.Attribute("X").Value);
```

Comment: XPath to extract all LocalPosition nodes, read attributes and use parent node if you need access to Screen node (for example to read the Name node).

Answer (score 2):

XPath would look like this:

```
/Settings/Display_Settings/Screen/LocalPosition/@X
```

You can use online tool like this: http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output to test your XPath's.
Also, there's a good tutorial here: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/

As long, as question was updated, code:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\darbai_test\so_Test.xml");
var screenPosition = xdoc
         .Descendants("Screen")
         .Descendants("LocalPosition")
         .Attributes("X");

foreach (var xAttribute in screenPosition)
{
    Console.WriteLine(xAttribute.Value);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```